# Find cell phone's public IP address for purpose of SSH'ing into EC2 server

Tags: ios, mobile, amazon-ec2, ssh, ip-address

Background: when I'm on call, I need to be able to quickly SSH into an AWS production server from my cell phone (e.g., if I don't have a laptop handy and there is cell coverage but no wifi). SSH access is only allowed from a small number of IP addresses, and before I can SSH I need to add my cell phone's public IP address to that list. I'm using Prompt 2 and AWS Mobile Console.

Question: how can I find my cell phone's public IP address that I need to add to the AWS security group? (please read the entire question before you close it as a duplicate)

It does sound easy, right? Except I cannot find an easy way to determine my cell phone's actual public IP address. For example, while accessing the internet via the cell phone network, whatismyip.com reports my public IP address as 107.77.xxx.xxx. Adding that address to the security group does not work. ipchicken.com and some other sites report the same address.

Next, I figured that there is probably all sorts of NAT in between, and that maybe some smarter web tools can handle that. Indeed, ifconfig.me and checkip.dyndns.org report a different public IP address, 166.170.xx.xx, in my case. Adding that address to the security group, also does not allow me to SSH into the server.

Now, as my last resort, I ssh'ed from my cell phone into another server that does not contain production data and allows ssh access from any address:

```
$ netstat -an|grep ":22 .* ESTABLISHED"
tcp        0      0 172.31.14.173:22        107.72.xx.xx:23255      ESTABLISHED
$
```

Per netstat, my ssh session is coming from IP address 107.72.xx.xx (full address redacted). Now, if I add *that* address to my AWS security group, I can finally ssh from my cell phone into the production server. So, this last method does yield the correct address that I need, but it's somewhat difficult to obtain, especially if I don't have access to another server that allows SSH from any address.

So, in short: is there a website like whatismyip.com or ifconfig.me that would give me access to my cell phone's "true" public IP address, as determined by netstat.

I'm using an iPhone so I cannot run local UNIX commands. My cell service provider is AT&T, if that helps. I also put my phone into field test mode, but it gives me only AT&Ts non-routable internal 10.x.x.x address.

Comment: Have you found that the `netstat` method returns a different address over time or from different locations? It sounds like web traffic gets proxied, so you would need to check the address via a non-HTTP method. [Getting a public IP without access to a browser? - Networking - Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1604506-getting-a-public-ip-without-access-to-a-browser) suggests using a DNS lookup to obtain the address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hats off to you! You nailed it. I hat to download the ISC dig utility first, but using `dig` indeed produced the correct result! Please add as an official answer if you care for the credits. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like web traffic gets proxied, so you would need to check the address via a non-HTTP method.

[Getting a public IP without access to a browser? - Networking - Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1604506-getting-a-public-ip-without-access-to-a-browser) suggests using a DNS lookup to obtain the address, which would avoid the proxy.

Answer (score 4):

Diclaimer: author of https://api.ident.me

Assuming the same IP is used for all SSH targets, ident.me should support your need: you can use SSH (eg `ssh -q v4.ident.me`) to find the IPv4 address used for SSH, assuming your NAT box uses the same one for other destinations. It also supports DNS lookup (eg `dig +short @v4.ident.me`) though that seems less likely to match reliably (eg if your ISP translates addresses based on the destination port).